# Maximising the angle between two points and a point on a line

Tags: geometry

'Given a line and two distinct points A and B on the same side of the line, find the point P on the line such that ∠APB is maximised.'

Just by drawing diagrams I think it is when the circumcircle of APB is tangent to the line at P, but I can't seem to get the algebra right. (I tried using cosine rule.) Please help!

Comment: Just like in the next question you posed, assume the line is on the $x$ axis, so that $P = (x_P ,\, 0)$, $A = (x_A ,\, y_A)$, and $B = (x_B ,\, y_B)$. Because the points are on the same side of the line, you can assume $y_A \ge 0$ and $y_B \ge 0$; and that $x_A \le x_P \le x_B$ if $x_A \lt x_B$; $x_B \le x_P \le x_A$ otherwise; you can verify this by drawing the situation. I believe the arctangent function is useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: maximum angle]Of all circles through $A$, $B$, and a point on line $CD$, the circle which is tangent to $CD$ is the smallest.

Let circle $APB$ be tangent to $CD$ at $P$, and join $PA$, $PB$, and $AB$.
Let $Q$ be any other point on $CD$, and and join $QA$, $QB$.

Since circle $AQB$ is greater than circle $APB$, and chord $AB$ is common to both, then arc $AFB$ subtends a smaller angle at the center of circle $AQB$ than arc $AEB$ subtends at the center of circle $APB$.

And angles at the circumference are half the angles at the center.

Therefore $$\angle AQB < \angle APB$$